# Ensure serial has been written before executing next line

Tags: arduino, serial

When executing the following code on my Arduino Micro, only the first line is printed:

```
void crash(void) {
    abort();
}

void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    while(!Serial.available()) {
        Serial.println("Please input something to begin");
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.println("First"); // Gets printed
    delay(500); // Make sure Arduino is done writing to the serial connection

    Serial.println("Second"); // Doesn't get printed
    crash(); // Makes the Arduino device crash
}

void loop(void) {

}
```

I would like to something like this to make the second line get printed, before the device crashes:

```
void setup(void) {
    Serial.begin(9600);

    while(!Serial.available()) {
        Serial.println("Please input something to begin");
        delay(500);
    }

    Serial.println("First"); // Gets printed
    delay(500); // Make sure Arduino is done writing to the serial connection

    Serial.println("Second"); // Doesn't get printed

    wait_for_serial_write(); // Not really a function

    crash(); // Makes the Arduino device crash
}

void loop(void) {

}
```

Which function can I use instead of `wait_for_serial_write`?

The reason I want to do this is because my Arduino crashes "randomly" so I have put some debug `Serial.println` statements, that I would like to see before the device crashes.

I also **cannot** use `delay` in my real code as the crash occurs while in a timer interrupt, where `delay` doesn't work.

Comment: I'm curious, what does `crash` do exactly?

Comment: @KevinMark Calls `abort` function which "Aborts the current process, producing an abnormal program termination." I don't know how it is implemented, but no code is run either in the timer or in the loop function. The Arduino doesn't reset either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Serial.flush()`](http://arduino.cc/en/Serial/Flush) is exactly what you're looking for.